# Why is Bokeh's plot not changing with plot selection?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, scikit-learn, bokeh

Struggling to understand **why this bokeh visual will not allow me to change plots and see the predicted data.** The plot and select (dropdown-looking) menu appears, but I'm not able to change the plot for items in the menu.

Running Bokeh 1.2.0 via Anaconda.  The code has been run both inside & outside of Jupyter.  No errors display when the code is run.  I've looked through the handful of SO posts relating to this same issue, but I've not been able to apply the same solutions successfully.

I wasn't sure how to create a toy problem out of this, so in addition to the code sample below, the full code (including the regression code and corresponding data) can be found at my github [here](https://github.com/alofgran/Drug-Price-Prediction) (**code:** `Regression&Plotting.ipynb`, **data:** `pred_data.csv`, `historical_data.csv`, `features_created.pkd`.)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import Select, DataRange1d, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

#Must be run from the command line
def get_historical_data(src_hist, drug_id):
    historical_data = src_hist.loc[src_hist['ndc'] == drug_id]
    historical_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'date'], inplace = True, axis = 1)#.dropna()
    historical_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(historical_data[['year', 'month', 'day']], infer_datetime_format=True)
    historical_data = historical_data.set_index(['date'])
    historical_data.sort_index(inplace = True)
    # csd_historical = ColumnDataSource(historical_data)
    return historical_data

def get_prediction_data(src_test, drug_id):
    #Assign the new date
    #Write a new dataframe with values for the new dates
    df_pred = src_test.loc[src_test['ndc'] == drug_id].copy()
    df_pred.loc[:, 'year'] = input_date.year
    df_pred.loc[:, 'month'] = input_date.month
    df_pred.loc[:, 'day'] = input_date.day
    df_pred.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'date'], inplace = True, axis = 1)
    prediction = lin_model.predict(df_pred)
    prediction_data = pd.DataFrame({'drug_id': prediction[0][0], 'predictions': prediction[0][1], 'date': pd.to_datetime(df_pred[['year', 'month', 'day']], infer_datetime_format=True, errors = 'coerce')})
    prediction_data = prediction_data.set_index(['date'])
    prediction_data.sort_index(inplace = True)
    # csd_prediction = ColumnDataSource(prediction_data)
    return prediction_data

def make_plot(historical_data, prediction_data, title):
    #Historical Data
    plot = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height = 800, x_axis_type = 'datetime',
                  toolbar_location = 'below')
    plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
    plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price ($)'
    plot.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
    plot.x_range = DataRange1d(range_padding = 0.0)
    plot.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3
    plot.title.text = title
    plot.line(x = 'date', y='nadac_per_unit', source = historical_data, line_color = 'blue', ) #plot historical data
    plot.line(x = 'date', y='predictions', source = prediction_data, line_color = 'red') #plot prediction data (line from last date/price point to date, price point for input_date above)
    return plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    ver = vselect.value
    new_hist_source = get_historical_data(src_hist, ver) #calls the function above to get the data instead of handling it here on its own
    historical_data.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(new_hist_source)
    # new_pred_source = get_prediction_data(src_pred, ver)
    # prediction_data.data = new_pred_source.data

#Import data source
src_hist = pd.read_csv('data/historical_data.csv')
src_pred = pd.read_csv('data/pred_data.csv')

#Prep for default view
#Initialize plot with ID number
ver = 781593600
#Set the prediction date
input_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31) #Make this selectable in future
#Select-menu options
menu_options = src_pred['ndc'].astype(str) #already contains unique values
#Create select (dropdown) menu
vselect = Select(value=str(ver), title='Drug ID', options=sorted((menu_options)))

#Prep datasets for plotting
historical_data = get_historical_data(src_hist, ver)
prediction_data = get_prediction_data(src_pred, ver)

#Create a new plot with the source data
plot = make_plot(historical_data, prediction_data, "Drug Prices")

#Update the plot every time 'vselect' is changed'
vselect.on_change('value', update_plot)
controls = row(vselect)

curdoc().add_root(row(plot, controls))
```

**UPDATED: ERRORS**:

1) No errors show up in Jupyter Notebook.

2) CLI shows a `UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be careated via a new attribute name`, referencing `historical_data.data = ColumnDatasource.from_df(new_hist_source).

Ultimately, the plot should have a line for historical data, and another line or dot for predicted data derived from sklearn.  It also has a dropdown menu to select each item to plot (one at a time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `update_plot` is a no-op that does not actually make any changes to Bokeh model state, which is what is necessary to change a Bokeh plot. Changing Bokeh model state means *assigning a new value to a property on a Bokeh object*. Typically, to update a plot, you would compute a new data dict and then set an existing CDS from it:

```
source.data = new_data  # plain python dict
```

Or, if you want to update from a DataFame:

```
source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(new_df)
```

As an aside, don't assign the `.data` from one CDS to another:

```
source.data = other_source.data  # BAD
```

By contrast, your `update_plot` computes some new data and then throws it away. Note there is never any purpose to returning anything at all from any Bokeh callback. The callbacks are called by Bokeh library code, which does not expect or use any return values.

Lastly, I don't think any of those last JS console errors were generated by BokehJS.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot.  I updated the code as you suggested.  Command line produce an `AttributeError("'ColumnDataSource' object has no attribute 'copy'")`.  I got rid of the `.copy()` methods from my `get_historical_data` and `get_prediction_data` functions, but still have the error.  Does assigning a change back to the original variable holding the data (i.e. `data = data.drop()`) qualify as "copying"?

Comment: I also tried leaving the data from the aforementioned functions as dataframes, but then I get an error `Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via anew attribute name`, but I believe you mentioned in another user's post that you weren't familiar with what that Pandas error meant...I figure it'd be better to keep it as a CSD if possible throughout the process though.

Comment: `from_df` is for adapting DataFrames to CDS format, so your `get_historical_data` should return a DataFrame, not a CDS. Just delete the line `prediction_data = ColumnDataSource(prediction_data)` entirely.

Comment: That was my thinking as well, and was consequently the reasoning behind my action in my second comment.  Unfortunately, I get that same warning (I incorrectly called it an 'error' in the comment above).

Comment: Updated code and errors in question above to indicate changes mentioned so far.

Comment: I've never seen that Pandas error message come from `from_df` before, so in order to investigate I would need an actual data set that reproduces the message to test with.

Comment: if you have a minute, data can be found in the GitHub repo linked at the top of the question.

Comment: After downloading the data, trying to run the code above yields "NameError: name 'lin_model' is not defined"

Comment: The Regressions&Plotting.ipynb notebook has the code mentioned in the question plus the “linear model” code required. You may have to change the data import lines to point toward your download location, but other than that the code & data should be self-sufficient.

Comment: So, speaking frankly, theres actually several things wrong with the code, on the Bokeh end, and on the Pandas end. There's not really one single question here, there's lots of things to fix. This is not really good for SO, which does not look kindly on iterative collaboration. If you close this question here, and open a topic on the project Discourse we can discuss at length. https://discourse.bokeh.org/

Comment: Otherwise, my meta-advice is to stop trying to solve your immediate problem. Take one of the much, much simpler examples we provide for people to study, and study it. E.g. the slider example is *prototypical*. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py  Your eventual working solution is going to look alot like it, so *start* with that. Understand it, and try to extend it *one small thing at a time* that way if you run in to issues along the way, you can ask very focused questions, about how to fix *a single thing*.

Comment: appreciate the candidness. I’ll open the topic in a couple hours as suggested. Thanks

Comment: I looked at the examples, but I’ll go back to them as well too. Thanks

Comment: I went through the example you provided and had some success in simplifying the code, but am still stuck.  I've moved my question to Discourse as suggested (https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/adding-sklearn-predict-data-to-plot/4358)

Comment: Great, I've started a discussion there. Would appreciate a question close here so there is not a lingering unanswered project question.